# CMD Opens then Blender Closes Instantlı

Tags: error

I installed Blender for the first time and when I tried to open it a blank CMD opened, a white Blender window popped up and everything closed immediately.

I checked almost every problem on this site and developer site but nothing solved my problem.

- My drivers are updated (also have the C++ redistributable 2013)
- Strangely, when I installed Blender, it didn't create a folder in %appdata%/Roaming (only in Program Files).
- I tried to install it using both the .msi and .zip with no success. And have uninstalled it three times.

I don't know what to do I have no further details about the program or the error I'm a newbie.

**Here's My Pc Specs:**

```
                 BIOS: BIOS Date: 03/27/18 16:06:01 Ver: 05.0000C (type: BIOS)
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.8GHz
               Memory: 8192MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 8078MB RAM
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
      Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Supported
      DxDiag Version: 10.00.17134.0001 64bit Unicode

                  Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 630
    Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
       Chip type: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
        DAC type: Internal
  Display Memory: 4166 MB
Dedicated Memory: 128 MB
   Shared Memory: 4038 MB
    Current Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (60Hz)

                  Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
    Manufacturer: NVIDIA
       Chip type: GeForce GTX 1050
        DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
     Device Type: Full Device
  Display Memory: 8057 MB
Dedicated Memory: 4019 MB
   Shared Memory: 4038 MB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and navigate to your Blender install folder (usually located under `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender`). From here you can click on the navigation bar [image]

and type `cmd`; this should open up a new command prompt at this folders location. From there in the console type `blender.exe`. It will laugh like regular, but the console will stay open. This way if your blender crashes you can read the console. If you are unable to solve the problem from there, go ahead and update your post with the error information.

Comment: Also, clarifying the version you are attempting to install would be helpful aswell.

Comment: I downloaded the beta test version and problem is gone